# Android Wear BoxInsetLayout doesn't work on Moto 360

Tags: wear-os, moto-360

I'm trying to make an Android Wear app that has two pages.
I created:

- InsetActivity
- GridViewPager
- FragmentGridPagerAdapter
- Two classes extended from CardFragment
- Two custom layout files that use BoxInsetLayout

One of the layout files is as follows:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/history_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="all">

        <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            android:id="@+id/history_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

InsetActivity.isRound() returns true, but BoxInsetLayout.isRound() returns false.

Two error messages are shown in console:

```
E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same issue. I've heard that there is some bug with that on moto, but with isRound() function

Comment: Now I use Activity/Fragment instead of InsetActivity/CardFragment, and LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout. I couldn't find what was the problem, but it's working now. [https://github.com/kazhik/Gambarumeter](https://github.com/kazhik/Gambarumeter)